# Force Option To Rename In Batch

Tags: batch-file

I need a way when moving a file in batch that it renames similar to windows explorer "copy and replace or keep both" The only options I get is overwrite Yes/No/All and I need Rename Yes/No/All

This is for an old command line video converter that can only handle one file at a time so Ive set the batch up like a assembly line

4 Folders
Queue
Inputfiles
Newfiles
Finished

It processes the video in inputfiles, moves the original and converted file to finished, moves a new video from queue to inputfiles and starts again. 
This is what I have now

```
for %%a in ("inputfiles\*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v wmv2 -qscale:v 1 -
preset veryslow -c:a pcm_u8 "newfiles\video.wmv"
for %%a in ("newfiles\video.wmv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vn 
"newfiles\audio1.wav"
for %%a in ("newfiles\audio1.wav") do xbadpcmencode "%%a" 
"newfiles\audio.wav"
xmvtool -v "newfiles\video.wmv" -a "newfiles\audio.wav" -o Merged1.xmv
del newfiles\audio1.wav
del newfiles\audio.wav
del newfiles\video.wmv
move /-y "Merged1.xmv" "Finished\"
move inputfiles\*.* finished\
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "queue\*.*" /B /O:D /S') DO SET 
NewestFile=%%I
move "%NewestFile%" "inputfiles\"
for %%a in ("inputfiles\*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v wmv2 -qscale:v 1 -
preset veryslow -c:a pcm_u8 "newfiles\video.wmv"
for %%a in ("newfiles\video.wmv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vn 
"newfiles\audio1.wav"
for %%a in ("newfiles\audio1.wav") do xbadpcmencode "%%a" 
"newfiles\audio.wav"
xmvtool -v "newfiles\video.wmv" -a "newfiles\audio.wav" -o Merged2.xmv
del newfiles\audio1.wav
del newfiles\audio.wav
del newfiles\video.wmv
move /-y "Merged2.xmv" "Finished\"
move inputfiles\*.* finished\
pause
```

As you can see Ive manually changed the output name in the second instance but what I want is to simply use one instance looped with it prompting to rename. Id rather not have to write this out 25 times with Merged1.xmv, merged2.xmv, merged3.xmv etc :)

Comment: @LotPings Any insight on the issue? I appreciate you cleaning up the post (I simply copied from my batch) As it stands now I moved forward a bit and am using a time stamp check to move files but Im still stuck having to write everuthing out over and over and I really want to just loop it

Comment: The edits you did to the batch though break it. Above works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81l9pbwxxIE thats it written out for 10 files. I tested the edits you did and it just errors "No such file or directory"